# how to parse dynamic logs using grok and logstash?

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

I 'm new in logstash and grok and trying to parse logs that look like this:

```
2019-10-23 08:44:38.457  INFO 99999 [ID1=645ae2ae-a9a6-412f-b079-f0495aa9b713, ID2=62702, ID3=3e37ee7c-4e09-4924-be2f-66008dd19032] ---
2019-10-23 08:44:38.796 DEBUG 99999 [ID1=6cf44468-5baa-470b-9ee2-2aa7a74a858f] ---
2019-10-23 08:44:38.849 DEBUG 99999 [ID3=5766d625-366b-4ce6-9a3a-f5e5db3ea65d, ID1=6cf44468-5baa-470b-9ee2-2aa7a74a858f] ---
```

UUID1 can be first or last.
UUID2 might not be present.

How could I parse with grok and keep all UUIDs if present?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This regex works ((?<=ID3=)[a-f0-9]+\-[a-f0-9]+\-[a-f0-9]+\-[a-f0-9]+\-[a-f0-9]+)

But when I put it together with (?<UUID3>((?<=containerId=)[a-f0-9]+\-[a-f0-9]+\-[a-f0-9]+\-[a-f0-9]+\-[a-f0-9]+)) it doesn't work

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use grok for that. I am sure it can be done, since you can have optional fields in a grok pattern, but I think dissect is a better match...

```
    dissect { mapping => { "message" => '%{[@metadata][timestamp]} %{+[@metadata][timestamp]->} %{level} %{pid} [%{[@metadata][kvStuff]}] %{}' } }
    date { match => [ "[@metadata][timestamp]", "YYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ] }
    kv { source => "[@metadata][kvStuff]" field_split => "," trim_key => " " }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.
But again I don't know which ID in which position every time. Could be [0] or [2] or not present.

Comment: @bbx402, how did you solve this problem? Thanks